# Mounting multiple directory's as an external volume - Docker

Tags: docker, containers, volumes

I am trying to run a Nginx Docker container with 3 directorys mounted as an external volume. When I mount just one the container is up and and running but when I mount 3 the container is created and then exits right away.

```
docker run -v ~/data/usr:/usr/share/nginx/ -v ~/data/etc:/etc/nginx/ -v ~/data/var:/var/log/nginx/ -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try mount each of them separately?

Comment: I just did now it seems to be -v ~/data/etc:/etc/nginx/ which is causing the container to exit

Comment: Is the volume mount hiding or replacing the `nginx.conf` in the image?  What's in the container logs?

Comment: Does the `~/data/etc` folder on the host contain the data that should be in `/etc/nginx` in the container? A lot of people assume the data from inside the container will be kept, but you're actually overwriting the `/etc/nginx` folder in the container with whatever is in `~/data/etc`

Comment: the ```~/data/etc``` folder on the host is empty. You recon that could be the issue?

Comment: As @timsmelik wrote this is probably the issue since you overwrite the default nginx config that is sitting in `etc/nginx` with nothing.

Comment: Probably, but run the `docker logs [CONTAINER]` command to see what the error is to be sure.